# How to find a dynamically assigned aura:id?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-recordeditform, aura-id

I'm looking for getting a dynamically assigned Aura:id. Below is my attempt to read it in Lightning:recordEditForm.

**Component markup:**

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    <aura:attribute name="conid" type="Id" default="null" />

    <aura:attribute name="fields" type="String[]" default="['Email','Birthdate']" />

    <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="conRecEdit" objectApiName="Contact" recordid="{!v.conid}" >
        <lightning:messages />
        <lightning:inputField aura:id="fname" fieldName="FirstName"/>   
        <lightning:inputField aura:id="lname" fieldName="LastName"/>    

        <aura:iteration items="{!v.fields}" var="f" >
            <lightning:inputField aura:id="{!f}" fieldName="{!f}"/>
        </aura:iteration>

        <lightning:button type="button" label="test" onclick="{!c.checkValue}" />
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
</aura:component>
```

**JS Controller:**

```
({
    init : function(component, event, helper) {
        var fld = component.find('fname');
        console.log('fld '+fld);
        if (fld!=null)
            fld.set('v.value', 'new name');

        var fld1 = component.find('Email');
        console.log('fld1 '+fld1);
        if (fld1!=null)
            fld1.set('v.value', 'test@test.com');
    },

    checkValue: function(component, event, helper){
        var fld1 = component.find('Email');
        console.log('fld1 '+fld1);

        if (fld1!=null)
            fld1.set('v.value', 'test@test.com');

    },
})
```

[image]

If we assign aura:id hard-coding it, it works perfectly fine. But if the id is assigned dynamically, seems it's not possible to find here.

Any clues, suggestions to workaround reading the aura:id in above working example. Much Appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`aura:id` [can't be populated dynamically](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_ids.htm):

> `aura:id` doesn't support expressions. You can only assign literal string values to `aura:id`.

Instead, give all of your `<lightning:inputField>` components a common `aura:id` so that you can find them, and then filter by the `fieldName` attribute:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.fields}" var="f" >
    <lightning:inputField  aura:id="contactField" fieldName="{!f}"/>
</aura:iteration>
```

then

```
let emailField = component.find('contactField').filter(x => x.get('v.fieldName') === 'Email')[0];
emailField.set('v.value', 'test@test.com');
```

Comment: Hi @David Reed Thank you, and appreciate for your help. worked perfect.

Comment: Probably could use `const` rather than `let`.