# How to set an input field value on change of checkbox

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-id, lightning-recordeditform

I'm trying to modify the field values using lightning:recordEditForm. I have one checkbox and one date time field. On change of the checkbox, current date time should be populated on to the date time field. Below is the code I'm using currently.

**HTML**

```
<aura:attribute name="fieldsList" type="FieldListController.wrapper"/> //wrapper class
<lightning:recordEditForm recordId="{!v.recordId}" objectApiName="Case" density='comfy' aura:id="recordEditForm" onsubmit = "{!c.handleOnSubmit}" onsuccess = "{!c.handleOnSuccess}" onload = "{!c.handleOnLoad}">
  <aura:iteration items="{!v.fieldsList}" var="field">
    <label>{!field.fieldLabel}</label>
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="{!field.fieldAPIName}" aura:id = "{!field.fieldAPIName}" variant = "label-hidden" onChange = "{!c.handleOnChange}"/>
  </aura:iteration>
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

**JS**

```
handleOnChange : function(component, event, helper) {
  var today = new Date();
    var fields = event.getParam('fields');
    if(fieldAPIName == 'Check_Box_Field__c') { //ensure value set is done only when checkbox field is changed
        component.find("Check_Box_Field__c").set("v.value", today.toLocaleString());
    }
}
```

When I try the above code, I'm facing "cannot read properties "set" of undefined. Because component.find("Check_Box_Field__c") returns undefined. Please suggest me a way to resolve this issue. Much appreciated.

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/263240/how-to-find-a-dynamically-assigned-auraid

Comment: TYSM @user6670. Worked as expected.